# vagrant disable password authentication not working

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I have added a new user to the vagrant machine. And now I am trying to ssh into the vagrant with the new user using public key and without password.

The vagrant file is:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.30"
end
```

Then I logged into the vagrant machine by doing `vagrant ssh`.
And then this is how I have added the new user to the vagrant machine:

```
sudo adduser new_user --disabled-password
sudo su - new_user
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
touch .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then I generated a new pair of public private key by doing

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "email@example.com"
```

Then I copied the public key into the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

I have also modified the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by changing the following lines

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

And then I try to ssh into the vagrant from my machine by doing

`ssh new_user@192.168.33.30 -i ../ssh_keys/vagrant`

But it is still asking for a password. How can I disable the password?

**UPDATE**
So, these are the logs:

`ssh vagrant@192.168.33.30 -v`

Logs:

```
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/payam/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.33.30 [192.168.33.30] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.33.30:22 as 'vagrant'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:3jRn/OmhK6LmNBtpZbgjM64I1+lougeAppjUcJDtQXA
debug1: Host '192.168.33.30' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/payam/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/payam/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
vagrant@192.168.33.30's password:
```

`ssh vagrant@192.168.33.30 -i .vagrant/machines/automation_node/virtualbox/private_key  -v`

```
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/payam/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.33.30 [192.168.33.30] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
load pubkey ".vagrant/machines/automation_node/virtualbox/private_key": invalid format
debug1: identity file .vagrant/machines/automation_node/virtualbox/private_key type -1
debug1: identity file .vagrant/machines/automation_node/virtualbox/private_key-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.33.30:22 as 'vagrant'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:3jRn/OmhK6LmNBtpZbgjM64I1+lougeAppjUcJDtQXA
debug1: Host '192.168.33.30' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/payam/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: .vagrant/machines/automation_node/virtualbox/private_key  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: .vagrant/machines/automation_node/virtualbox/private_key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
vagrant@192.168.33.30's password:
```

This is using a new pair of private/public key that I generated myself. The public key is added to `/home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys`. And here I am providing the private key to ssh `ssh vagrant@192.168.33.30 -i ../ssh_keys/vagrant_automation_node  -v`

```
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/payam/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.33.30 [192.168.33.30] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ../ssh_keys/vagrant_automation_node type 0
debug1: identity file ../ssh_keys/vagrant_automation_node-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.33.30:22 as 'vagrant'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:3jRn/OmhK6LmNBtpZbgjM64I1+lougeAppjUcJDtQXA
debug1: Host '192.168.33.30' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/payam/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: ../ssh_keys/vagrant_automation_node RSA SHA256:jPKUlxB/TMj0TVOug3DVZZdwhC7eUz6/Zl3WGOCgQwY explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: ../ssh_keys/vagrant_automation_node RSA SHA256:jPKUlxB/TMj0TVOug3DVZZdwhC7eUz6/Zl3WGOCgQwY explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
vagrant@192.168.33.30's password:
```

In all cases the authentication falls back to password.

Comment: Please run ssh with the "-v" flag to print debugging info, then [edit] your question to include the debugging info.

Comment: @Pay OK, I have edited my answer to add further debug avenues to explore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition of adding `-v`, to check if ssh does take the right key, see if the following can help:

- using `ssh -i ../ssh_keys/vagrant new_user@192.168.33.30`, to make sure the -i option is taken into account
- make sure the public key was copied as *one* line in the vagrant remote machine `~new_user/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- make sure the private key is not *passphrase* protected (I generally make those with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "email@example.com" -P ""`)

Since `ssh vagrant@192.168.33.30 -i ../ssh_keys/vagrant_automation_node  -v` does not work, and if [restarting the VM](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/1936#issuecomment-126159440) is not enough, activate [the debug option on the sshd process](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging_and_Troubleshooting#Debugging_a_server_configuration)

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -D -dd
# or
/usr/sbin/sshd -D -E /home/<user>/sshd.debug.log
# or
/usr/sbin/sshd -D -dd -f /home/<user>/sshd.debug.log
```

The goal is to check on the server side why your public key is rejected.

---

From [the discussion](http://%20I%20found%20it...%20%20%20%20Somehow%20there%20was%20an%20already%20existing%20network%20adapter%20on%20my%20PC%20which%20had%20the%20ip%20address%20192.168.33.1%20with%20subnet%20/24.%20Meaning%20everytime%20I%20was%20trying%20to%20ssh%20into%20my%20vagrant%20machine%20which%20was%20given%20a%20static%20IP%20of%20192.168.33.10,%20I%20was%20actually%20hitting%20the%20other%20network%20adapter.%20That%20also%20explains%20why%20nothing%20was%20getting%20logged%20on%20the%20vagrant%20machine%20in%20the%20sshd...%20Basically%20everytime%20I%20was%20doing%20anything%20with%20an%20IP%20address%20in%20the%20subnet%20192.168.33.10/24%20it%20was%20hitting%20my%20own%20adapter%20on%20windows,%20thus%20never%20even%20reached%20the%20VMs%20I%20changed%20the%20VMs%20IP%20addresses%20and%20now%20everything%20works), the [OP Payam Mesgari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5138122/payam-mesgari) confirms:

I found it...

> Somehow there was an already existing network adapter on my PC which had the ip address 192.168.33.1 with subnet /24.
>
> Meaning everytime I was trying to ssh into my vagrant machine which was given a static IP of 192.168.33.10, I was actually hitting the other network adapter.
> That also explains why nothing was getting logged on the vagrant machine in the sshd...
>
> Basically everytime I was doing anything with an IP address in the subnet 192.168.33.10/24 it was hitting my own adapter on windows, thus never even reached the VMs.
> I changed the VMs IP addresses and now everything works

Comment: Before I activate the log, I see something else happening. When I do ssh via local host and port forwarding by doing `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2206 -vvv`, everything works as expected. It only asks for password when I use the private network of the vagrant machine, the `192.168.33.30`.

Comment: @PayamMesgari port forwarding is the `-L` option (example: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example). `-p` is just to access an ssh daemon running on a different port than the standard one: no "forwarding" involved.

Comment: @PayamMesgari Activating the `sshd` debug logs is a good way to at least check anything is getting to that daemon. But if it is running on port 2206, then your `ssh -v` questions should include `-p 2206`

Comment: I understand. I tried the command `/usr/sbin/sshd -D -dd` but it says `Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.` and then `Cannot bind any address`

Comment: @PayamMesgari Yes, you need to stop the sshd service first (In the target vagant VM you want to connect to), then restart it with the debug option.

Comment: Thanks! The debug is active but it looks like nothing is even hitting the debugger. The debug is `Server listening on :: port 22.`. Then I tried doing `ssh -i ../ssh_keys/vagrant_automation_node vagrant@192.168.33.30 -vvv` but it again asks for password and nothing logs on the debugger.

Comment: @PayamMesgari "Then I tried...": When you start doing ssh (on default port 22), do you see anything in the sshd session?

Comment: Yes, when I just do `vagrant ssh` from my pc then I see the logs appearing on the vagrant machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218967/discussion-between-vonc-and-payam-mesgari).

Comment: @PayamMesgari Good catch and well done. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.